# Angular JS with jQuery Datepicker, scope issue inside ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I need to use jQuery datepicker with Angular and I am new to both :-(. I am able to use the datepicker as an angular directive. However, I am running into a few  issues.

Please look at this plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/Gm2qeKA1qdyxPGCnGaHH?p=preview

When I select a date (either date 1 or date 2) using the datepicker in the header, it updates the model. The changes are correctly reflected in the first table. But for date 1, the hidden input value is not being updated despite of the model being updated. This can be verified by clicking the button at the bottom.

Secondly, changing date 1 or date 2 from at row level (inside ng-repeat) doesn't update the model. The change is not reflected in the first table. But the input value is being updated. If the input value is updated why the model is not being updated as they are bound together?

```
<input type="hidden" id="{{x.id}}_DatePicker_1" ng-model="x.date1" datepicker="true" />
<input type="text" id="{{x.id}}_DatePicker_2" ng-model="x.date2" datepicker="true" />
```

Also, a weird issue (I think). When the data is loaded for the first time, opening the datepicker for a row level datepicker (inside ng-repeat) shows the initial value as selected only for date 2, i.e. datepicker on text box. But the initial value is not shown as selected for date 1, i.e. datepicker on hidden field.

Certainly, I am doing multiple things wrong but I find myself unable to figure it out. Will appreciate the help, understanding the errors I have made and get a working version of my plunker, preferably with all use cases working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ant experts care to help please?